# Recursively remove nodes when children are empty in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to using xsl and I am not sure how to remove specific parent nodes and all their children, if all are empty. I think the answer shown in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910199/xsl-ignore-empty-children-recursively) is what I need, but I am not sure how to apply this to a specific node instead of the whole stylesheet.

Using what is in that question, I have expanded it ...

```
<farm>
    <foo>
    <bar>
        <baz/>
    </bar>
    <quux>  </quux>
    <quuux>Actual content</quuux>
    </foo>
    <sounds>
        <moo>
            <meow>
                <buzz></buzz>
            </meow>
        </moo>
        <birds>
            <cluck>  </cluck>
            <quack></quack>
        </birds>
    </sounds>
</farm>
```

How can I just eliminate `<sounds>` and all of its children (if they are all empty) while leaving empty nodes like foo, bar, and baz. The requirements for the xml I am producing needs to have certain tags present even if they are blank, but some need to be removed if they are blank.

To go even further, if what I had is ...

```
<farm>
    <foo>
    <bar>
        <baz/>
    </bar>
    <quux>  </quux>
    <quuux>Actual content</quuux>
    </foo>
    <sounds>
        <moo>
            <meow>
                <buzz>"zzzz"</buzz>
            </meow>
        </moo>
        <birds>
            <cluck>  </cluck>
            <quack></quack>
        </birds>     <!-- Fixed by edit -->
    </sounds>
</farm>
```

In this example,`<sounds>, <moo>, <meow>`, and `<buzz>` would need to stay since `<buzz>` has a value, but `<birds>` and its children would need to be removed.

This seems so complicated to me, I am not sure what the simplest way to do this would be.

Thank you so much for your guidance, as I feel dizzy from going in so many circles!

Comment: I don't understand you question. Is there a list of elements you want to keep even if they are empty? If so, how would it look in the given examples? -- BTW, `cluck` is not really empty - so I guess you want to consider whitespace-only as empty?

Comment: Also tell us which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Answer (score 2):

If your processor doesn't support XSLT 3.0, here's an XSLT 1.0 option...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[ancestor-or-self::sounds][not(string())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle for example #1: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rNp

Fiddle for example #2: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rNp/1

Comment: Yes, we are using version 1. I will try this and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @Shysoks - Were you able to resolve your issue or are you still having problems?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming XSLT 3 (supported for the Java platform with Saxon 9.8 and 9.9 and for the .NET platform with Saxon 9.8, also by Altova 2017/2018/2019) you could use `xsl:where-populated` together with `xsl:next-match` for `sounds` and any descendant elements and the identity transformation for the rest; additionally you would need to strip white space, otherwise `<cluck>  </cluck>` would not be removed:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="sounds | sounds//*">
      <xsl:where-populated>
          <xsl:next-match/>
      </xsl:where-populated>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiKn/0 has your first input and https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiKn/1 your second.